# SFMC MobileConnect QueueMO : Pass & Get addtional parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, mobileconnect

I am using the below request for calling the /sms/v1/queueMO from external website.

**Basic one - Working**

```
{
"mobileNumbers": [
"1xxxxxxxxx"
],
"shortCode": "xxxxx",
"messageText": "KEYWORD"
}
```

We wanted to send additional parameters like MemberCID. I have tried this one, but not able to send and get the value in SFMC

**Not Working - Passing additional MemberCID parameter**

```
{
"mobileNumbers": [
"1xxxxxxxxx"
],
"shortCode": "xxxxx",
"messageText": "KEYWORD",
"MemberCID": "P22222"
}
```

Is there way to pass the additional parameters to the QueueMO from the external application? If so, can you guide me how to pass and get the value in SFMC?

Comment: where and how are using these additional parameters?

Comment: Hi @EazyE, After receiving the message with additional parameters, I will use it in one of the data extensions in  marketing cloud. We use it for other functionalities and opt out process.